# Downloaded Videos Not Playable on Android Version <= 6.1

Tags: java, android, video, mp4

I have a video downloader android application It's allow people to download videos from twitter and Something has changed in 2 months Downloaded videos are not playable on Android version <= 6.0 Error is : "Can't Play This Video" Some of these videos playable but most of it is not. same format mp4.

I didn't make any changes in my code. I tried download files manually from browser and still error is occurs.

```
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;

// File url to download
private static String file_url = "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1122253815884001280/pu/vid/1280x720/xTTWb4wnRMvFzpXk.mp4";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);

}

/**
 * Showing Dialog
 * */

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setMax(100);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        return pDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to download file
 * */
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%
            // progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);

            // Output stream
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                    + "/2011.mp4");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

    }

}
```

I want to make these videos playable as others. Some of the mp4 videos plable and most of its is not. I don't know the reason is codec or not but I want to make these playable too.

This videos is example of situation.

https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1122253815884001280/pu/vid/1280x720/xTTWb4wnRMvFzpXk.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example video uses H.264 profile of `High @Level 3.` Not supported in Android version `<= 6`. 
H.264 is the *"image"* format of the video (where audio is MP3/AAC).

Lowest-to-high Profie order is: Baseline --> Main --> High.

See docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#video-codecs

[image]

[**MediaInfo**](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download) analysis:

```
Video
ID                             : 1
Format                         : AVC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                 : High@L3.1
```

Normally you fix by offering alternate encodings of the video file from your site. Since you're not in charge of Twitter server, you'll have to check if Twitter itself is keeping any Low/Standard-Def versions of uploaded videos, for older devices that can't handle High-Def. If found, then just offer users a multiple choice of "quality" links.

Alternatively try to see if FFmpeg can play the format. Try VLC Player app (is FFmpeg powered) on a problematic device. If it plays okay, then try importing [**Android-FFmpeg**](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&ei=rFzLXIV08uKDB9eFqdAM&q=Android+FFmpeg) into your app code, where you use it to decode/play the downloaded videos in your app.